# Limiting number of selected items in CARTO category widget?

Tags: carto

I created a map with several widgets with CARTO but I'd like to limit the number of selected items in a category widget to one. By default you can select all of the items and in my use case that is not desirable, because there's some points overlapping making it confusing for the users.

I've already looked through the documentation and did some tests, but couldn't find a way to do it, so I'm asking for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to CARTO BUILDER then the answer is **no**, you cannot limit or define the number of entries to show on the widget.

On the other hand, if you are talking about a [CARTO.js dataview](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartodataviewcategory) or an [Airship web component](https://carto.com/developers/airship/reference/#/components/category-widget), then yes, you can limit the number of entries in the category widgets, just check the docs I've linked.